# How to change a webpage to make the login page unique?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a website that requires a login to go to the games section. I would like to know how to make the individual's username appear on the page they have logged into. For example, if I logged into the website with the username, 'Cooper' and the login information was correct, I would like to be able to have 'Welcome, Cooper' at the top of the webpage they have logged into. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you post a piece of your code what have you tried so far? I'm also missing info from where do you want to take user's name (database, session etc)

Comment: @JanZahradník, there is no code for it at all. I have a .htaccess file that controls who is allowed to access the specific webpage, but that is all I have so far.

Answer (score 1):

Use session

1) assign session in your login validate

```
$_SESSION['Name'] = "Cooper";
```

2) print session on the page you like

```
print "Welcome ".$_SESSION['Name'];
```

*dont forget to start session on the top of your pages

```
session_start();
```

Comment: How do I put this in a document?